# Thread per connection or thread-pool in a MMO server?

Tags: java, mmo, multithreading

So I'm writing this MMO server, and I'm really struggling in this topic. I'm writing a fast paced MMO, and the server max players would be 800.

I have read that one thread per connection is not a good idea, and also that thread-pooling is not ideal in some cases.

I think 800 threads listing for client message is bit to much. In my case, which approach is better?

Comment: I don't think _"fast paced MMO"_ is a good match for _"800 threads"_...

Comment: What about [netty](http://netty.io/)?

Comment: With 800 threads you'll get more trouble that you would get with a threadpool. So go with a threadpool. One thread per connection is always bad, for several reasons.